# Why do I get "System.Data.DataRowView" instead of real values in my WinForms Listbox?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Whenever I run my code and try to view a `highscore` all I get back in my listbox is `System.Data.DataRowView`.

Can anyone see why?

Code:

```
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    
string sqlStr = "SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' ', Score) as NameAndScore " + 
                "FROM highscore ORDER BY Score DESC";
    
MySqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConn);
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
dAdapter.Dispose();
lstNames.DisplayMember = "NameAndScore";
lstNames.DataSource = dTable;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I always have to deal with this problem, even if I set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMembers` of the List Box.

Your current code is correct and should work, if you need access to the current selected item value of any column of your `dTable` you can get them doing this:

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)lstNames.SelectedItem;
String valueOfItem = drv["NameAndScore"].ToString();
```

What I like about getting the entire `DataRowView` is that if you have more columns you can still access their values and do whatever you need with them.

Answer (score 7):

The following code should work:

```
DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
dAdapter.Fill(dSet);

lstNames.DisplayMember = "NameAndScore";
lstNames.ValueMember = "NameAndScore";
lstNames.DataSource = dSet.Tables[0];
```

If it does not work, please update your question and provide us with some information about the columns and values that are actually returned in `dSet.Tables[0]`.

Comment: not entirely sure how to find the return value for dSet.Tables[0] but when i tested i still got 'Sytem.Data.DataRowView' in the listbox

Comment: Have you ever debugged? Set a breakpoint to the `lstNames.DisplayMember = ...` line, right click the `dAdapter` word and then quick inspect it. In that window, you can also enter a value like `dAdapter.Tables[0][0]` to see the properties of the first row.

Comment: i set the breakpoint but i cannot find an option to inspect dAdapter when i right click?

Comment: It may be called "Quick Watch"

Answer (score 5):

Set your [`lstNames.DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) and [`lstNames.ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) fields.

> Gets or sets the property to display for this ListControl.

---

> Gets or sets the path of the property to use as the actual value for
>   the items in the ListControl.

This should solve your problem..

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'DataTextField' and no extension method 'DataTextField' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Thats the error i receive when i set the two

Comment: @CainNeal Your `lstNames` is `ListBox` or not?

Comment: This just gives me the System.Data.dataRowView as i got initially, i just asked DarK but could i use a label instead of a listbox?

Comment: @CainNeal _Well_, I'm not sure your _"how to use adapter"_ or _"which control should I use"_ questions but I'm sure if you want to get real values of your listbox, you should set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties.

Comment: I did set both DisplayMember and ValueMember properties but it gave me the same input to my listbox

Comment: The values appear to be `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`. There don't appear to be `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember` available in the ASPX side when declaring the asp:ListBox control.

Comment: Follow-up; realized I am working in a webform and this is a winform question; that's why I did not see `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember` properties.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in the comments, please add lstNames.DataBind() to your code.

```
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

string sqlStr = "SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' ', Score) as NameAndScore " + 
                "FROM highscore ORDER BY Score DESC";

MySqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConn);
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
dAdapter.Dispose();
lstNames.DisplayMember = "NameAndScore";
lstNames.ValueMember = "NameAndScore";
lstNames.DataSource = dTable;
```

EDIT:

Can you try this instead:

```
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

    string sqlStr = "SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' ', Score) as NameAndScore " + 
                    "FROM highscore ORDER BY Score DESC";

  myConn .Open();

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, SQLConnection1);


      SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      while (rd.Read())
      {
        lstNames.Items.Add(rd[0]);
      }
      rd.Close();
      rd.Dispose();
      myConn.Close();
```

Comment: It wont allow me to use .DataBind. It says that lstNames does not contain a definintion, but it will let me use .DataBindings

Comment: Looks like you're using a ListControl not a ListBox, so can you please just add the valuemember (see edit) and remove the databind?

Comment: I still only receive 'System.Data.DataRowView' would i be able to use the above code if i used a label instead of a listbox? but obviously change the lstNames

Comment: Forget about `DataBind`. This does not exist in WinForms and it is not necessary, as obviously data binding is already happening - otherwise you'd not see any items in your list.

Comment: For the above code i get a return in the listbox 'Byte[]Array'

Answer (score 1):

If you want your list box to show values from an specific column of the data source use

`lstNames.DataTextField = "SpecialColumnName";`

Answer (score 1):

Only the order of the calls is wrong. First set the `DataSource` and only after that set the display member:

```
lstNames.DataSource = dTable;
lstNames.DisplayMember = "NameAndScore";
```

Comment: `and only AFTER that set the display member` is a key.

Answer (score 0):

I use :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in _dataGridView.SelectedRows)
{
    var rowObject = row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
    var array = rowObject.Row.ItemArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem of picking a single value from a populated Listbox and getting `System.Data.DataRowView`.
I was able to solve it by casting the selected item to `System.Data.DataRowView` and then 
accessing the Row and ItemArray subclasses:

```
var si = ListBox1.SelectedItem; 
string val = ((System.Data.DataRowView)si).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question. Just thought it might be nice to add  an update to the answers given already. I was looking for a solution to the same problem. I the realized it is in which order you place these 3 lines of code

```
lstNames.DisplayMember = "NameAndScore";
lstNames.ValueMember = "NameAndScore";
lstNames.DataSource = dTable;
```

It should use the datasource first. Then The value member and then the display member
As follow:

```
lstNames.DataSource = dTable;
lstNames.ValueMember = "NameAndScore";
lstNames.DisplayMember = "NameAndScore";
```

Answer (score -1):

just make sure you are typing the name of field same as in datasource in other word it is a case sensitive

so :
 Me.GridLookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "**cur_code**"
is different than 
 Me.GridLookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "**CUR_code**"

Answer (score -1):

if you copied the object instead of placing as a new object it will do this. Try deleting the object and putting it back on. I had the same issue and this is what I did. Don't know why it worked, but it did.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes what might cause it is mis-spelt displaymember variable name.

Comment: Not an answer. Please use comments for such remarks, or consider converting this to an elaborated answer.