# "Failed to convert parameter value from a DataRowView to a Int32" message on running a code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to load some image data stored on SQL server from .Net but while starting an error appearances on screen with a message : Failed to convert parameter value from a DataRowView to a Int32
But I don't know where is the problem.

Code of this part:

```
try
    {
    conn.Open();
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Pictures WHERE ID = @ID";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conn);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID" ,SqlDbType.Int).Value = listBox1.SelectedValue;
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Pictures");
    byte[] arrPic = (byte[])(ds.Tables["Pictures"].Rows[0]["Pic"]);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arrPic);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    conn.Close();
}
catch (SystemException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Error is on "da.Fill(ds, "Pictures");"

Comment: so `listBox1.SelectedValue` is not an Integer,

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428542/why-i-get-system-data-datarowview-instead-of-real-values-in-my-listbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listBox1.SelectedValue
```

returns an object, not an integer. Try converting it like

```
 da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID" ,SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedValue);
```

as @Kevin pointed out in his comments, you may have to use a different approach if the `listBox` is actually returning an entire `DataRowView`. Something like

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)listBox1.SelectedItem;
String valueOfItem = drv["TheColumnYouActuallyWant"].ToString();
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID" ,SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(valueOfItem);
```

as illustrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428542/why-i-get-system-data-datarowview-instead-of-real-values-in-my-listbox) question.

Comment: The question states "DataRowView to a Int32", can `ListBox.SelectedValue` return a `DataRowView`?  Must be doing something really strange if so...

Comment: @Stone yea, honestly have no idea. Regardless though, assuming the actual value is an int, this should work. if it isnt....well....who knows lol