# C# WPF get listview value from multiple selected row

Tags: c#, listview

im using WPF in c#.
How to get all the value of the row selected from column M.

Image of listview
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [ListView.SelectedItems Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396),

```
foreach (var item in myListView.SelectedItems)
{
    //do something with the values, maybe add to a list?
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)lstNames.SelectedItem;
    String valueOfItem = drv["NameAndScore"].ToString();
}
```

Basically replace "NameAndScore" by your column name.

Reference: [Why I get “System.Data.DataRowView” instead of real values in my Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15437668/6741868)

Comment: it returns System.Data.DataRowView. how to get the specific column value?